# Yii2 Bad Request (#400)

Tags: php, yii2-advanced-app

I am trying  to login into my system after adding this code in my system it gives me  bad request method
Since I dont want to disable the CSrf Method
This is in layouts/main.php

```
<div class="wrap">
    <?php
    NavBar::begin([
        'brandLabel' => Yii::$app->name,
        'brandUrl' => Yii::$app->homeUrl,

    ]);
    $menuItems = [
        ['label' => 'Home', 'url' => ['/site/index']],
    ];
    if (Yii::$app->user->isGuest) {
        $menuItems[] = ['label' => 'Login', 'url' => ['/site/login']];
    } else {
        $menuItems[] = [
                'label' => 'logout('.Yii::$app->user->user->identity->username.')',
                 'url' =>['/site/logout'],
                 'linkOptions' =>[
                        'data-method'=> 'post'
                ]
        ];
    }
```

Then the SiteController.php

```
public function actionLogin()
    {
        if (!Yii::$app->user->isGuest) {
            return $this->goHome();
        }

        $this->layout = 'blank';

        $model = new LoginForm();
        if ($model->load(Yii::$app->request->post()) && $model->login()) {
            return $this->goBack();
        } else {
            $model->password = '';

            return $this->render('login', [
                'model' => $model,
            ]);
        }
    }
```

Comment: Would be helpful to add the error message.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you have this in your layout file:

```
<?php $this->registerCsrfMetaTags(); ?>
```

And you will also need a csrfInput in your form.
If you did not generate your form with [ActiveForm](https://www.yiiframework.com/doc/api/2.0/yii-widgets-activeform), you have to manually add that, e.g.:

```
<input type="hidden" name="<?= Yii::$app->request->csrfParam; ?>" value="<?= Yii::$app->request->csrfToken; ?>" />
```

> csrfParam is "_csrf" by default, but use it like this. You may want to rename it in the future.